# Simple ActiveRecord Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

I have a database model set up such that a post has many votes, a user has many votes and a post belongs to both a user and a post.  I'm using will paginate and I'm trying to create a filter such that the user can sort a post by either the date or the number of votes a post has.  The date option is simple and looks like this:

```
@posts = Post.paginate :order => "date DESC"
```

However, I can't quite figure how to do the ordering for the votes.  If this were SQL, I would simply use `GROUP BY` on the votes `user_id` column, along with the `count` function and then I would join the result with the posts table.

What's the correct way to do with with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use the [counter cache mechanism](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) to store the vote count in `Post` model.

```
# add a column called votes_count
class Post
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Now you can sort the `Post` model by vote count as follows:

```
Post.order(:votes_count)
```

2) Use `group` by.

```
Post.select("posts.*, COUNT(votes.post_id) votes_count").
  join(:votes).group("votes.post_id").order(:votes_count)
```

If you want to include the posts without votes in the result-set then:

```
Post.select("posts.*, COUNT(votes.post_id) votes_count").
  join("LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id=posts.id").
  group("votes.post_id").order(:votes_count)
```

I prefer approach 1 as it is efficient and the cost of vote count calculation is front loaded (i.e. during vote casting).

Comment: Awesome.  The first approach is exactly what I was looking for.  Can I do this with will_paginate?  In other words, can I do the following: `Post.order(:votes_count).paginate`?

Comment: Yes. You can chain `paginate`

Answer (score 1):

Just do all the normal SQL stuff as part of the query with options.

```
@posts = Post.paginate :order => "date DESC", :join => " inner join votes on post.id..." , :group => " votes.user_id"
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class

So I don't know much about your models, but you seem to know somethings about SQL so

named scopes: you basically just put the query into a class method:

```
named_scope :index , :order => 'date DESC', :join => .....
```

but they can take parameters

```
named_scope :blah, {|param| #base query on param }
```

for you, esp if you are more familiar with SQL you can write your own query,

```
@posts = Post.find_by_sql( <<-SQL ) 
  SELECT posts.*
  ....
SQL
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this within the model itself?  When I display several posts, right now I have to do a separate query for each of their votes.

Comment: use the :include option might  help. If this is a query you access often try a named scope http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/named_scope

Comment: Named scopes look really useful.  I've actually never heard of them (I'm still pretty new to Rails).  Could you show me how I would use them with my model?  Thanks.

Comment: I can try, I'd have to think about the group by stuff, so if you know how already i wont bother, try find_by_sql, I can look into how it works with will_paginate